# jQuery draggable revert based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am having an issue related jQuery draggable and droppable. Here is description something what I want to do.

**First:** I have two divs. One is `<div id="selected">` and another is `<div id="container">`. "container" has 10 `<li>` which are draggable and droppable into "selected". Here is code:

```
<div id="selected">
    <ul class="sortable-list">
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="container">
    <ul class="sortable-list">
             <li>1</li>
             <li>2</li>
             <li>....</li>
             <li>9</li>
             <li>10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Second:** I want to allow any 5 `<li>`s from "container" to "selected" div. If someone tries to add 6th `<li>`, then it must not allow user to it. That is the 6th `<li>` that is going to be inserted into "selected" must be reverted using [jQuery draggable option revert](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-revert).

i.e. `$("#container li").draggable({ revert: true });`
Here is javascript code for that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var total = 0;
    $("#selected").droppable({
        drop: function() {
                total = $("#selected li").length;
                //alert(total);
                if (total >= 5) {
                    $("#container li").draggable({ revert: true });
                } else {
                            // below code is not working
                    $("#container li").draggable({ revert: false }); // this is making whole feature weird. I can drag all the <li> anywhere
                }
            }
    });
});
```

This is working fine.

**Third:** But when I drag an `<li>` from "selected" to "container", the "selected" div will have only 4 `<li>`s. So in this situation, later on user should be able to add another `<li>` into "selected" div from "container" div. But unfortunately it is not working. All the `<li>`s I try to drag and drop into "selected" are being reverted due to `if (total >= 5 )` condition.

Can anyone help me to solve this out using [draggable revert](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-revert) option? Please...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [`accept` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) which takes a function to do this much easier, like this:

```
$("#selected ul").droppable({
    accept: function() {
        return $("#selected li").length < 5;
    }
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HemSU/).  When you drag elements out, the `.length` goes down and it'll accept elements again...no reason to get any more complicated :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yes, it is working. Here the new issue is that I can see that I am dragging LI element from "container" to "selected". But while dragging  LI from selected to container, It seems that element is not being dragged. But at the end, I can see that LI is moved from selected to container. Is there any solution to see the drag effect while dragging from selected to container?

Comment: @lakum4stackof - you should be getting the effect, are you still adding/removing draggable anywhere?

Comment: @Nick Craver - I don't see the drag effect while dragging from selected back to container div. But in end, as a result I am getting LI moved from selected div to container div and the LI is added at the end of the LI list every time.

Comment: @lakum4stackof - oooh, I see what you mean, here ya go: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/HemSU/1/

Comment: @Nick Craver - Hey dear, whenever I drag and drop LI from container to selected or selected to container, it always drops LI at the end of whole LI list. I can't drop it between two LI elements. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @lakum4stackof - you can use the `placeholder` option, and just change the `append` code, if it was a sortable then it would already do this

Comment: @Nick Craver - Actually I am new to jQuery. I am not getting what should I do with sortable. Please tell me is you have some idea.

Comment: @lakum4stackof - You're mixing up different questions here, and expanding this one in comments...you should as that as a different/separate question, so SO isn't cluttered up with "question creep" like this :)

Comment: @Nick Craver - Ok. I have created a separate question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304121/jquery-droppable-based-on-condition

Answer (score 3):

First of all, setting `revert` to false, will disable the revert function entirely. As you point out, you'll be able to drop the draggables anywhere. What you usually want is `revert: 'invalid'` which means that it'll revert whenever it's dropped on anything that isn't a droppable that accepts it.

What you want to do ought to be something like this:

```
$('#selected').droppable({
    drop: function() {

       // since you're doing a full re-calc every time, this doesn't need to be global
       var total = $("#selected li").length;

       if(total >= 5) {

           // once you've reached five, simply don't accept any more elements
           // the rest will revert if dropped here
           $('#selected').droppable('disable');
       }
    }
});
```