# jQuery UI Draggable revert to original position if moved less than a certain distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery UI to make an object draggable.

I know how to make the object revert to its original position in all cases using:
`$("#draggable").draggable({ revert: true });`

However, how can I make an object revert back only when it has moved to the left or to the right 80% of its width?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302882/jquery-draggable-revert-based-on-condition Use the `accept` function to check if dropping is allowed

Comment: @django how's that new answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can revert conditionally based on your start position determined in the `start` event.

```
$('.dataCard').draggable({ axis: 'x', 
    revert: function() {
        //determine the start/end positions
        var end = $(this).position().left;
        var start = $(this).data('start');
        //subtract end and start to get the (absolute) distance
        var distance = Math.abs(end - start);
        var width = $(this).width();
        //if the distance is more than 80% of the width don't revert
        if(distance > (width * .8))
        {
             return false;
        }
        //else revert
        return true;
    },
    start: function(){
        //get the start position
        var start = $(this).position().left;
        //store the start position on this element
        $(this).data('start', start);
    }
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/uFrC5/5/)